# primary key and index concept

Tags: indexing

I create a column as primary key , does this create indexes automatically ? or do i need to create  indexes explicitly. i was under assumption that primary key also maintains indexes

Comment: depends on the database implementation - what database are you interested in??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server creating a Primary key will create a Unique Clustered Index on that Column.
or more specifically from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

> Note  PRIMARY KEY constraints create
>   clustered indexes automatically if no
>   clustered index already exists on the
>   table and a nonclustered index is not
>   specified when you create the PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint.

Comment: so there is not need to create index explicitly rite ?

Comment: If you don't already have a clustered index already specified on the table and you are not telling it to use a diff non-clustered index then the index and constraints will be automatically created for you. (As an FYI a clustered index physically sorts the order of the data so there can only ever be one clustered index per table)

Comment: Another note you mention indexes (plural). Creating the primary key creates a single clustered index it doesn't magically figure where indexes are needed and create them for you. You may find that you will need to add some non-clustered indexes to improve performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should clear out some air.

```
--creating a table without any primary key
CREATE table understanding_indexes
 (P_Id int,
 LastName varchar(255),
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Address varchar(255),
 City varchar(255)
 )
 --
 --checking for indexes
 sp_helpindex understanding_indexes
```

OUTPUT

```
 The object 'understanding_indexes' does not have any indexes, or you do not have permissions.

--ADDING A NOT NULL CONSTRAINT
ALTER TABLE UNDERSTANDING_INDEXES 
ALTER COLUMN P_Id INTEGER
NOT NULL

--ADDING A PRIMARY KEY Constraint, can only be done on column which are not null.
ALTER TABLE UNDERSTANDING_INDEXES
ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)

sp_helpindex understanding_indexes
```

OUTPUT

```
PK__understa__A3420A5702084FDA  clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY  P_Id
```

Overall, As soon as you add a primary key constraint on a table, it automatically adds clustered indexes on the table.

This illustration is on SQL Server 2008 R2.